# DataGridView CellMouseEnter detecting grey area

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, cursor

i'm trying simulate a hover event in a `DataGridView` control to show a `Cursor.Hand` when a `DataGridViewImageColumn` has hovered

I'm trying this (suscribe to `CellMouseEnter`)

```
dgv_tabla.CellMouseEnter += dgv_tabla_Hover;
```

And checking if `RowIndex` is not -1

```
private void dgv_tabla_Hover(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //The index of the column where i want to show Cursor.Hand
    var index = dgv_tabla.Columns["Remove"].Index;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    else
        dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

The problem, is when i'm hovering "Remove" cell and move the mouse down (to the ''grey area''), then, the `Cursor.Hand` dont change to `Cursor.Default`

Image to understood better:
[image]

Is any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to code the mousemove event and maybe do a hittest there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the `MouseMove` event and do a `HitTest` [as suggested by TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675948/datagridview-cellmouseenter-detecting-grey-area#comment90315614_51675948) in the comments above. In this case, your code would look something like this:

```
dgv_tabla.MouseMove += Dgv_tabla_MouseMove;


private void Dgv_tabla_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = dgv_tabla.Columns["Remove"].Index;

    DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dgv_tabla.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (info.ColumnIndex == index && info.RowIndex >= 0)
        dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    else
        dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CellMouseLeave` event to reset the cursor to default. In this case you don't need the `else` branch:

```
dgv_tabla.CellMouseEnter += dgv_tabla_Hover;
dgv_tabla.CellMouseLeave += dgv_tabla_CellMouseLeave;

private void dgv_tabla_Hover(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //The index of the column where i want to show Cursor.Hand
    var index = dgv_tabla.Columns["Remove"].Index;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void dgv_tabla_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgv_tabla.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```